# How can I add extra view component class paths in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, domain-driven-design

### The problem

The default namespace for view components is `App\View\Components` with the folder being `app/View/Components`. I am setting up a DDD file structure and wish to do two things:

1. Move "shared" view components to a namespace and folder of `App\ViewComponents` and `src/app/ViewComponents` respectively
2. Have view components specific to individual "apps" with their own namespace and folder of `App\MyApplication\ViewComponents` and `/src/app/MyApplication/ViewComponets` respectively.

The new `App` namespace/folder setup is done via composer psr-4 autoload keys and works fine. But Laravel always used the `App\View\Components` namespace when trying to load components.

### My attempt

I have solved the first part of my problem, but I am hoping that there is a better way. For instance when I want to move views, I can just set the `view.paths` config directive in my `AppServiceProvider` but I don't see a similar way of, essentially, adding namespaces to where Laravel looks for view components. So what I ended up doing was:

- Create a `ViewServiceProvider` class, extending `Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class` and point to it in `bootstrap/app.php` instead
- In there, override the `registerBladeEngine` method, in there pointing towards my own `BladeCompiler` class instead of the built-in one

```php
public function registerBladeEngine($resolver)
{
    // The Compiler engine requires an instance of the CompilerInterface, which in
    // this case will be the Blade compiler, so we'll first create the compiler
    // instance to pass into the engine so it can compile the views properly.
    $this->app->singleton('blade.compiler', function () {
        return new BladeCompiler(
            $this->app['files'],
            $this->app['config']['view.compiled'],
        );
    });

    $resolver->register('blade', function () {
        return new CompilerEngine(
            $this->app['blade.compiler']
        );
    });
}
```

- In my own `BladeCompiler` class, which extends `Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler`, override the `component()` and `compileComponentTags()` methods - basically anywhere that referenced `View\\Components` - with pretty much a carbon copy but instead using `ViewComponents` and also made sure that where they return a `Illuminate\View\Compilers\ComponentTagCompiler` I instead referenced my own `ComponentTagCompiler`
- In my own `TagCompiler` I override the `guessClassName()` method, again with essentially a carbon copy, just renaming `View\\Components` to `ViewComponents`

As you can see, that's quite a lot of work just to change the path. And I also want to add *another* path. Multiple "apps" run under the same Laravel codebase, so for instance we might have `App\Website\`, `App\Admin` and `App\Blog` and, depending on which app is currently running, load a different namespace for the running app, i.e. the blog would be `App\Blog\ViewComponents` pointing to `src/app/Blog/ViewComponents`.

Is there a way to achieve this without as much overriding as above? If not, can you suggest a way to achieve the second part of the requirement?

**Note:** I haven't ruled out using sub folders and continuing with everything under the main `App\View\Components` namespace just yet - I don't want to fight Laravel more than I have to and am willing to concede if there's no better way, but if I can achieve the folder structure I want it would feel a lot tidier.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to make laravel search in several different directories for view components? Or is it about finding the blade template files in directories called different than "views" (default)?

Comment: Yes I want to *change* the default view components directory then also dynamically add *another* directory based on the current "app" for it to search. (Maybe the `view.paths` is a bit misleading - I don't want to do anything with views, this was just an example of how I achieved the same thing for views, that I want to do with view components).

Comment: @Douma what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update; got a working implementation by using a configuration and php 8 annotations

Follow the steps below to make it possible to add more lookup folders for the blade view components feature, based on your question and details you have provided. It would have helped to have posted that code you already had. But I have added a possible solution to get it to work, using Annotations and using a config with a namespace/path map.

Depending on how you switch between one application and the other, from which the details are not provided in your question, you have to modify the way the configuration is retreived in the `MyComponentTagCompiler` class.

### Blade compiler

In order to change the `ComponentTagCompiler` we need to change the `BladeCompiler` class:

```php
namespace App;

class YourBladeCompiler extends \Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler
{
    protected function compileComponentTags($value)
    {
        if (! $this->compilesComponentTags) {
            return $value;
        }

        return (new \App\MyComponentTagCompiler( //it is about this line 
            $this->classComponentAliases, $this->classComponentNamespaces, $this
        ))->compile($value);
    }
}
```

### Service provider

Now register the `YourBladeCompiler` in `YourViewServiceProvider` :

```php
class YourViewServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider
{
    public function registerBladeEngine($resolver)
    {
        $this->app->singleton('blade.compiler', function () {
            return new \App\YourBladeCompiler( //it is about this line 
                $this->app['files'],
                $this->app['config']['view.compiled'],
            );
        });

        $resolver->register('blade', function () {
            return new CompilerEngine(
                $this->app['blade.compiler']
            );
        });
    }
}
```

### MyComponentTagCompiler

This is an implemention I created that works with PHP 8 Attributes, given below:

```php
namespace App;

#[\Attribute]
class ViewComponentName
{
    public string $name;
    public string $package;

    public function __construct(string $name, string $package)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->package = $package;
    }
}
```

With this attribute, you can declare the package name and component name on the view component class (see example at the bottom). So during lookup the component can be matched on these parameters.

But you can change it to your own requirements if needed.

What it does:

- It first let's Laravel lookup the View Component through it's own mechanisms, in the `parent::componentClass` method.
- If no component is found and an exception (`InvalidArgumentException`) is thrown, after which my implementation will walk through the given paths and namespaces (from the `getLookupPaths` method) and see if an attribute matches the component name and package name. If so it returns this class and the view component is loaded accordingly.

```php
namespace App;

use App\View\ViewComponentName;
use Illuminate\View\Compilers\ComponentTagCompiler;

class MyComponentTagCompiler extends ComponentTagCompiler
{
    protected function getLookupPaths() : array
    {
        /*
         * add some logic here to get an application specific configuration
         * since you have multiple application in one, I cannot know it works in your
         * application, since the details are not provided in the question 
         */
        return config('view_component_paths');
    }

    private function getFiles(string $dir) : array
    {
        return scandir($dir);
    }

    private function isPhpFile(string $file) : bool
    {
        return strpos($file, ".php");
    }

    private function getClassNamespace(string $file, string $folderNamespace) : string
    {
        $class = str_replace(".php", "", $file);
        $classNamespace = $folderNamespace . "\\" . $class;
        return $classNamespace;
    }

    private function getComponentName(string $file, string $namespace) : ?ViewComponentName
    {
        $classNamespace = $this->getClassNamespace($file, $namespace);
        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($classNamespace);
        if(method_exists($reflection, 'getAttributes')) {
            $attribute = $reflection->getAttributes()[0];
            if ($attribute->getName() == ViewComponentName::class) {
                return $attribute->newInstance();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function componentClass(string $component)
    {
        try {
            parent::componentClass($component);
        } catch(\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            list($lookupComponentPackage, $lookupComponentName) = explode("-", $component);
            foreach($this->getLookupPaths() as $namespace=>$dir) {
                foreach ($this->getFiles($dir) as $file) {
                    if ($this->isPhpFile($file)) {
                        if($componentName = $this->getComponentName($file, $namespace)) {
                            if($componentName->name == $lookupComponentName && $componentName->package == $lookupComponentPackage) {
                                return $this->getClassNamespace($file, $namespace);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

Where the config contains (config/view_component_paths.php):

```php
return [
    "App\\Test"=>__DIR__ . "/Test/"
];
```

If you wish to replace the default laravel behavior completely or do not like my implementation based on annotations, consider implementing your own version of the method:

```php
public function componentClass(string $component)
{
    //return the class name here based the component name
    //without calling parent
    dd($component); 
}
```

### Example view component

```php
namespace App\Test;
use App\View\ViewComponentName;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

#[ViewComponentName('test', 'namespace')]
class MyViewComponent extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.test');
    }
}
```

In blade:

```
<x-namespace-test />
```

It should now be working. I think this is enough information to give you an idea of how to implement this in your own application. There seems to be no other way than to extend some base classes. But looking at this answer, it is possible to create a high level implementation based on a global lookup configuration and php annotations (or some other mechanism you wish, for example converting the class name with namespace to a view component name).

### Old answer

## Problem 2 as defined in your question

> Have view components specific to individual "apps" with their own namespace and folder of App\MyApplication\ViewComponents and /src/app/MyApplication/ViewComponets respectively.

Sadly there seems to be no way of defining multiple class paths for view components in Laravel. But you can however change the application path and namespace prefix. As far as I found out you only have to overwrite the following properties in the `Application` class.

### bootstrap/app.php

Replace the following lines:

```php
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);
```

With:

```php
class YourApplication extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
{
    protected $namespace = "App\\MyApplication";
    protected $appPath = __DIR__ . "/../app/MyApplication";
}

$app = new YourApplication(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);
```

This is enough to change the app folder to another and gives you an idea of how to change it dynamically for having multiple apps in different namespaces. If you now run laravel commands like `php artisan make:component Test1234` it is created in your new app folder: `app/MyApplication/View/Components/Test1234.php`.

### Hardcoded paths

Some paths like `View/Components` are hardcoded in Laravel, and therefor not that easy to change. If you change as defined above, in this case the view components namespace becomes: `App\MyApplication\View\Components` and the path: `app/MyApplication/View/Components`.

## Problem 1 as defined in your question

> Move "shared" view components to a namespace and folder of App\ViewComponents and src/app/ViewComponents respectively

When you change application paths as explained above it is not possible to have a "shared" View Component folder. Laravel, as it seems, has only one default View Components path, which is based on hard coded paths and a dynamic namespace prefix as explained above. But you can of course, create a shared namespace and register the view components manually:

### View component (app/ViewComponents/ folder)

```php
namespace App\ViewComponents;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Test extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.test');
    }
}
```

Don't forget the components.test blade view.

### ServiceProvider

```php
\Blade::component("shared-test",\App\ViewComponents\Test::class);
```

### Blade

```
<x-shared-test />
```